# How to config quarkus application not build again?

Tags: java, build, quarkus

Enviroment :k8s

Issue : I change ip,port,username,password database in application.properties file, I must build my application again to update new information.

Expect :
When I change database information(Example: ip,port) in application.properties, I want my quarkus application will not build again.

Comment: ... What? Sorry, I do not understand the question. Please [edit] the post and clarify the actual problem.

Comment: When I change connection database information in application.properties. I want my application does not build again

Comment: What do you mean by this? Is your IDE building the applicatoin automatically? Or do you mean you do not want the devmode to restart when you change the property? Do you want maven to not build everything again when you call `mvn package`?  Again: please [edit] the post and clarify.

Comment: Do you want the changes to take place without the need of recompilation?

Comment: Yep! I don't want it recompile again when i change those information

Comment: I thought config those information as variable to I can put from outside

Comment: I recommend reading [Quarkus' Configuratoin Reference Guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference). There are multiple options to achieve what you want.